# Share enums between model and view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Is it a good idea to share enums between model and viewmodel?

I have pretty much common enums to share like:

```
public enum Month { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December }
```

or

```
public enum WeekDay {
    [EnumDescription("working day")]
    WorkingDay,
    [EnumDescription("weekend")]
    WeekEnd,
    Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
}
```

I use these enums in viewmodel now, and I want to move them to my model's namespace. But it will make my view dependent on the model:

```
@using MyApp.Model
```

What's the best place to share enums in the project and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely it's a good idea. Sometimes the easiest way is to build a separate assembly, maybe suffixed with `.Common`. Then, all assemblies can reference that without circular reference issues.

Answer (score 2):

Such general-purpose enums are like any other cross-cutting concerns: They are not themselves part of any layer, but should be put into a separate namespace or project, since they are not specific to any architectural layer. This way, you also get rid of any unwanted dependencies.